# What does the virtual keyword, in actionscript, does?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have found some code that uses the  `virtual` keyword for functions, like:

```
package tryOut{
    public class Parent {

        public function Parent() {}

        public function foo():void{
            trace("Parent foo");
        }//foo

        public virtual function bar():void{
            trace("Parent virtual bar");
        }//bar      
    }//class
}//package
```

As far as I understand using the `virtual` keyword should modify the way overriding a method works, or the way using a child method would work, or something. But it seems it does nothing at all. Having the extention:

```
package tryOut {
    public class Child extends Parent {
        public function Child() {}

        public override function foo():void {
            trace("Child foo");
        }//foo

        public override function bar():void {
            trace("Child virtual bar");
        }//bar

    }//class
}//package
```

The following code prints:

```
var parent:Parent = new Parent();
var child:Child = new Child();

parent.foo(); //Parent foo
child.foo(); //Child foo
parent.bar(); //Parent virtual bar
child.bar(); //Child virtual bar

var childCast:Parent = child as Parent;

parent.foo(); //Parent foo
childCast.foo(); //Child foo
parent.bar(); //Parent virtual bar
childCast.bar(); //Child virtual bar
```

So both methods work the same regarding the override. Does the `virtual` keyword changes something I am missing?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From the help documents (If you're using Flash, do a search for 'virtual'):

> There are also several identifiers
>   that are sometimes referred to as
>   future reserved words. These
>   identifiers are not reserved by
>   ActionScript 3.0, though some of them
>   may be treated as keywords by software
>   that incorporates ActionScript 3.0.
>   You might be able to use many of these
>   identifiers in your code, but Adobe
>   recommends that you do not use them
>   because they may appear as keywords in
>   a subsequent version of the language.

```
abstract boolean byte cast

char debugger double enum

export float goto intrinsic

long prototype short synchronized

throws to transient type

virtual volatile
```

So in AS3, virtual does absolutely nothing.

Comment: And the actual page is, for anyone interested: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3_Flex/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f9b.html

Comment: Thanks LopSae, I actually just happened to have Flash open at the time, so I used the offline help.

Answer (score 1):

> So both methods work the same regarding the override.

What makes you think that? The tests you've shown aren't comparable.

`childCast` is typed as a `Parent`, yet you still end up calling the function in `Child`.

You don't check the same situation for the non-virtual method.

Comment: My bad, I corrected the example. Even so, the behavior keeps the same.